# Group Policy in Hierarchical Active Directory Domains

Tags: active-directory

We are currently designing a Domain Structure.

We would like to have a hierarchy of domains, where a group ploicy on the root domain would propogate to the sub domains.

We would also like it such that the administrators of the sub domains are not able to block this group policy.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a 'block policy inheritence' setting sitting between the parent and child DCs (it's set on the AD object for the child domain).

You can untick it and policies will start cascading down.

To prevent blocking of a GPO, select 'enforce' on it.